# textFieldDidEndEditing is not called and validations are not checked

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4

I am creating a sign up view(form) with Fullname, Email, Password and Verify Password as textfields. And I want to use validations as "mandatory field" incase of error while user inputs the data. I have created extension for UITextField and String. But I found that textFieldDidEndEditing is not called and validations are not checked. Anyone help me to solve this issue ?

//UITextField

```
import UIKit

extension UITextField {

func addLeftPadding() {
    let view = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 40))
    self.leftView = view
    self.leftViewMode = .always
}

func addWarning(warningMessage message:String) {
    self.removeWarning()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:self.frame.minX,y: self.frame.maxY + 2 , width:self.frame.width,height:15))
    label.tag = self.tag
    label.text = message
    self.superview?.addSubview(label)
}

func removeWarning() {
    for subView in (self.superview?.subviews)! {
        if let label = subView as? UILabel , label.tag == self.tag {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}

}
```

//String

```
import UIKit
extension String {

var isEmail: Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: self)
}
}
```

//SignUpController

```
import UIKit
import Material

class SignUpController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var fullName: TextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Email: TextField!


@IBOutlet weak var PasswordField: TextField!

@IBOutlet weak var NewPassword: TextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    prepareFullNameField()
    prepareEmailField()
    preparePasswordField()
    prepareNewPasswordField()


    self.fullName.delegate = self
    self.Email.delegate = self
    self.PasswordField.delegate = self
    self.NewPassword.delegate = self


    fullName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    fullName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next

    Email.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    Email.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next

    PasswordField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    PasswordField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next

    NewPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    NewPassword.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done

//prepareResignResponderButton()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

 }
 extension SignUpController {
    fileprivate func prepareFullNameField() {

        fullName.placeholder = "Name"
        fullName.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
    fileprivate func prepareEmailField() {

        Email.placeholder = "Email"
        Email.textColor = UIColor.white
    }



    fileprivate func preparePasswordField() {

        PasswordField.placeholder = "Password"
        PasswordField.textColor = UIColor.white
    }

    fileprivate func prepareNewPasswordField() {



        NewPassword.placeholder = "Verify Password"
         NewPassword.textColor = UIColor.white
    }

 }
 extension SignUpController: UITextFieldDelegate {


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    if textField == fullName {
        fullName.resignFirstResponder()
        //Email.becomeFirstResponder()

        Email.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if textField == Email {
        Email.resignFirstResponder()
        PasswordField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if textField == PasswordField {
        PasswordField.resignFirstResponder()
        NewPassword.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    else{
        NewPassword.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}

func dismissKeyboard() {

    fullName.resignFirstResponder()
    Email.resignFirstResponder()
    PasswordField.resignFirstResponder()
    NewPassword.resignFirstResponder()
}
//    public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
//        (textField as? ErrorTextField)?.isErrorRevealed = false
//        print("none")
//    }



func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    switch textField {
    case fullName:
        if fullName == nil {

            textField.addWarning(warningMessage: "mandatory_field")
            print("hmmmmmmmmm")

        }else{
            textField.removeWarning()
        }

    case Email:
        if Email == nil {
            textField.addWarning(warningMessage:"mandatory_field")
        }else{
            textField.removeWarning()
        }

    case PasswordField:
        if PasswordField == nil  {
            textField.addWarning(warningMessage: "invalid_email")
        }else{
            textField.removeWarning()
        }

    case NewPassword:
        if  NewPassword == nil {
            textField.addWarning(warningMessage: "minimum_password")
        }else{
            textField.removeWarning()
        }


    default:
        print("default")
    }
}


public func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    (textField as? ErrorTextField)?.isErrorRevealed = false
    print("good")
    return true
}

 //    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
 //        (textField as? ErrorTextField)?.isErrorRevealed = true
//
 //        print("ok")
//        return true
//    }

 }
```

Comment: Actually you didn't done any validation in `textFieldDidEnd`. You just checking only either textfield is empty or not.

Comment: dahiya_boy@@ Yes, I mean to say the same. Please help me, I am newbie in swift.

Comment: Now the point is, when you not done the validation then how validation is checked?

Comment: dahiya_boy @@ No, its not that. While user inputs data for full name, email, password and verify passwords, the error msgs should be seen on label below textfields. The warning "mandatory field" must be shown below textfields. Did you get it ?

Comment: You need error msgs below textfield? Like android toast you are asking.Is it?

Comment: @KajolBhatia I got it. Your question is too board. Lots of things that you are doing can be done on the storyboard and things can be done more simple way.

Comment: @KajolBhatia Toast is just a msg that comes for a sec, i think it is different from your req.

Comment: RAGHUNATH @@ dahiya_boy@@ its not a toast. The warning should come below textfields.

Comment: @KajolBhatia I got ur requirement, it is too board. So divide your question and ask where you facing issue.

Comment: don't go like android.It won't be good, show alert or show toast for 2 seconds. its easy..

Comment: RAGHUNATH @@ I know it, It's clients requirements to do so.

Comment: dahiya_boy @@ Is it too broad ?? then, please tell me why "textFieldDidEndEditing" is not called ??

Comment: @KajolBhatia Is `textFieldShouldReturn ` is called properly?

Comment: dahiya_boy @@ yes, it's called properly. I just verified it.

Comment: @KajolBhatia `textFieldDidEndEditing ` is called when you resigned first responder of that TF. Make sure you'r doing this.

Comment: dahiya_boy @@ No. For the first time when I resign the first responder, all other labels get hidden automatically. It's not working.

Comment: So I assume that TextField is a subclass and all of them have the delegates linked correctly because you say the `textFieldShouldReturn` is called.  So does the 'textFieldEndEditing` never get called even when switching between inputs or is it just not called at a particular time say when tapping a button?

Comment: Nevermind, that was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to validate the text fields.

```
 if (textField.text.isEmpty) {

            let alert = UIAlertView()

            alert.title = "No Text"

            alert.message = "Please Enter Text In The Box"

            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")

            alert.show()

 }
```

I have also used the same code for validating text field in Swift version 3.

Comment: I didn't mean this. I know how to do it.